# How to make image fill entire button JavaFX

Tags: java, css, image, javafx, imageview

I want to make image to fit entire button with no extra space. I have tried this, but its not working:

```
 .toggle-button {
 -fx-background-image: url("close.png");
 -fx-background-repeat: stretch;
 -fx-background-position: center center;
}

 .toggle-button:selected{
 -fx-background-image: url("contact.png");
}
```

This is the result I get:

[image]

How to make that exit picture (red square) fill entire button?

Comment: try `background-size:100% 100%`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the background-size, otherwise the background size is set to zero. Try the following:

```
.toggle-button  {

    -fx-min-height: 132px;

    -fx-min-width: 128px;

    -fx-background-image: url("close.png");

    -fx-background-size: 100% 100%;

    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;

    -fx-background-position: center 8px;

}
```